# Django model translation - cannot import name 'Constraint'

Tags: python, django, django-models, internationalization, translation

I want to translate content of my models fields with [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation).

When i run one of these:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py runserver
```

I get ImportError: cannot import name 'Constraint'

Here is the traceback of the 'makemigrations'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/modeltranslation/admin.py", line 20, in <module>
    from modeltranslation.translator import translator
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/modeltranslation/translator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from modeltranslation.manager import (MultilingualManager, MultilingualQuerysetManager,
  File "/home/mat/Desktop/python/pmm/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/modeltranslation/manager.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.where import Constraint
ImportError: cannot import name 'Constraint'
```

I use django1.9 and the latest django-modeltranslation.

If you cant help me with error, please recommand any other model translation app.

I have came across some of them:

[django-multilingual-ds9](https://github.com/ziima/django-multilingual-ds9)

[django-dbgettext](https://bitbucket.org/drmeers/django-dbgettext/overview)

[django-transmeta](https://github.com/Yaco-Sistemas/django-transmeta/)

But they seem to be no longer supported. Do you know if any of these works , or do you know about any other working solution ?

If that matters i have to admit i use [django-rosette](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta)

Comment: I think this is caused by an incompatibility with Django 1.9. I have had problems in the past with these kind of packages when there is an updated Django version. Maybe you have better luck with libraries that do require to update your model. You can see alternatives here: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-translation/ ordered from most recommended to least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found other app for model translation, [django-hvad](https://github.com/kristianoellegaard/django-hvad).

Works like a charm, have full django1.9 support, is easy to implement and is translator-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the latest django-modeltranslation? The issue was reported a while ago (https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/349) and already fixed in version 0.11rc1 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-modeltranslation/0.11rc1).

Comment: I have already seen that issue and yes, as long as pip provide latest version i do have 0.11rc1

Comment: As far as I know pip won't provide you with a Release Candidate version. As of today a `pip install django-modeltranslation` will point to version 0.10.2 of the package.